# Accessing widgets in one Activity from another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget

I want to access widgets in one `Activity` and make them invisible in another `Activity`.

**Activity 1**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
```

**Activity 2**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

    EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    if(name.getText().toString().equals("john"){
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can make the button hidden from activity 2?

Comment: can you please let us know how you can show One.class Button in two.class please we have to learn how this possible.

Comment: i don't know how to do this that's why i'm asking.

Comment: First of all this is not possible can you please let me know what actually you trying do so we can try achieved your requirement another way.

Comment: i am making a game and when the person finises the level i want the next level to to avalible e.g. true

Comment: not clear what your try to do can you please more elaborate ?

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` ([official guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html))

Comment: @AndrewT. i think you have to read question carefully before given any suggestion.

Comment: @Haresh I have read the question carefully, and I fully understand the problem. My suggestion is to use what I wrote before, or use `Intent` and `onCreate()`/`onResume()`. The usage is dependent on the user case.

Comment: @AndrewT. So have you think is possible to show One activity button in two activity ?

Comment: @Haresh I assume he wants to hide a button in activity 1 from activity 2. I know it is impossible & wrong to refer the button by using OP's code. The reason is Android only displays 1 activity at a time and all other activities will be stored on the back-stack. That's why I suggest 2 ways, which will **make activity 1 do the hiding instead**. One of them is Juan's answer. And the key is on the `Intent`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the intent you are using to start the second activity to pass the argument you need.
To put arguments in an intent you use any of the `intent.putExtra` methods. You can find all the method's descriptions [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20double%5B%5D)).
So if you want to put a boolean value, you would do something like:

```
secondActivityIntent.putExtra("my_bool", false);
```

And then start your second activity, then on your second activity you can get your parameter with:

```
getIntent().getBooleanExtra("my_bool");
```

the different methods to retrieve data can also be found in the previous link.

Also, to make views invisible you should use the `button.setVisibility(View.GONE)` or `button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` methods and not `button.setEnabled(false);`

Hope it helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can hold visibility of the button inside an application singleton:

```
public class App {
    static private App instance;

    private boolean buttonVisible;

    private App(){
        buttonVisible = true;
    }

    public static App getInstance() {
        if (instance==null)
            instance = new App();
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean isButtonVisible() {
        return buttonVisible;
    }

    public void setButtonVisible(boolean buttonVisible) {
        this.buttonVisible = buttonVisible;
    }
}
```

The first Activity can set visibility of its button inside onStart() method
according to the visibility state:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    findViewById(R.id.button).setVisibility(
        App.getInstance().isButtonVisible()?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
}
```

The second Activity can change the visibility state using

```
    EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    if(name.getText().toString().equals("john"){
        App.getInstance().setButtonVisible(false);
    }
```

Every time first activity gets focus, it runs its onStart() method and the button will be either visible or invisible according to the visibility state in the App singleton.

Answer (score 0):

in the first Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static MainActivity mThis = null;
.
.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mThis=this;
    .
    .
}
```

}

in the second activity:

```
TextView txt=MainActivity.mThis.findViewById(R.id.txtFrom);
txt.setText("Hellow I'm From Second Activity");
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make the button invisible or click able false

Comment: The question was *how* to do that.